# How to use if statement based on variable in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement

For a shell script the variable is a table name.

```
If the table name is test then execute

while IFS=',' read a; do drop.sh $a; done < abc

or else execute 

while IFS=',' read a; do create.sh $a; done < abc
```

How can i achieve this in Linux

Comment: [Tests and Conditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals) is a useful guide section here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an if - else statement like this;

```
if [ test ]
then
  do something
else
  do something else
fi
```

In your case

```
if [ "$yourVariable" = "test" ]
then
  while IFS=','...
else
  while IFS=','...
fi
```

See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html) for more, it is bash specific, but mostly usable for other linux shells.

**Edit** As suggested in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400457/how-to-use-if-statement-based-on-variable-in-shell-script#comment73862227_43400641), here are some other resources:

- [Bash guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) ([relevant page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals))
- [bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php) ([relevant page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest))
- [the POSIX spec for `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)

Comment: Please *don't* point folks at the ABS -- it's rather infamous for promoting bad practices in its examples. The [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) is a much more effectively-maintained introduction (with its relevant page [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals)), as is [the bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php), which covers `test` [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest). By contrast, [the POSIX spec for `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) will apply to *all* POSIX shells.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple conditions of the same type, you can also use the `case`:

```
for table in test bla something; do

    case "$table" in
        test)
            echo actions for $table
            ;;
        bla)
            echo another actions for $table
            ;;
        *)
            echo actions for anything other as test or bla eg for $table
            ;;
    esac

done
```

output from the above

```
actions for test
another actions for bla
actions for anything other as test or bla eg for something
```

e.g. for you case, you could write

```
table="test"

while IFS=, read -r a; do
        case "$table" in
                test) drop.sh "$a"  ;;
                *)  create.sh "$a"  ;;
        esac
done < abc
```

Some notes:

- always use `read -r` unless you know why don't want the `-r`
- always quote the variables like `"$a"`
- You `while read`-ing the same `abc` for the both cases, so DRY (don't repeat yourself) and move the `while read...` outside of your condition...